# USB sound interface problem

Tags: 12.04, sound, usb

I have a USB sound interface that I can't quite get working.
The device INPUT shows up in the system settings, but no output is available.

I have been wrestling with this thing for 2 months and have been able to uncover LITTLE.
Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks.

Ubuntu 12.04 64bit
M-Audio Fast Track MKII

Comment: if you open `sound preferences > hardware` the device does not show up? what's the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: Yes... I can see the input device, just no output device. lsusb shows the device as well.
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0763:2024 Midiman M-Audio Fast Track MKII

Comment: Further note - If I unplug the interface and plug it back in, I can see the output device in the system settings, but I still can't get sound. Makes me believe that something in the start up is not initializing the device. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is really lame, guys.
The problem was that I was plugged into a USB 1.1 in stead of a USB 2.0 connection. After making that correction and about 2 hours of fighting (violently) with Jackd, I am up and running!